# How to call restfull API inside router using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to retrieve data that is at this link: https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/cost using express.js.

I created the Single Page Application website using react.js for frontend so i need to call this route : `/shipping/check/cost` in my backend for get the data. but i dont know how to request inside router express.

I have never done a Restful API from someone else's website.
I just copied what was in the documentation, but in the documentation using the node.js not express.js. https://rajaongkir.com/dokumentasi/starter#cost-response

when I run this I get nothing.

**My routes**

```
import {Router} from 'express';
import * as ShippingRouter from './controller'

const routes = new Router();

routes.post('/shipping/check/cost',ShippingRouter.checkCost);

export default routes;
```

**Controller**

```
import db from '../../config/conn';
import keys from '../../config/keys';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import qs from 'querystring';
import request from 'request';
export const checkCost =(req,res)=>{
    var options = {
        "method": "POST",
        "hostname": "api.rajaongkir.com",
        "port": null,
        "path": "/starter/cost",
        "headers": {
            "key": "mykey",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    };
   var reqCost= https.request(options,function(ress){
       var chunks = [];

       ress.on("data", function (chunk) {
           chunks.push(chunk);
       });

       ress.on("end", function () {
           var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
           res.json(body.toString());
       });
    })
    reqCost.write(qs.stringify({
        origin: '501',
        destination: '114',
        weight: 1700,
        courier: 'jne'
    }));
    reqCost.end();


}
```

Comment: You don't show where you call the API? Also, please elaborate on "I get nothing" - you get no data? You get no network request? You get no error? etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is if the POST HTTP verb you are using is the correct one. You said you wanted to get data from the API, in this case, you should be using GET instead of POST (check the API documentation to know more).

Besides that, please check [this repository](https://github.com/agencyenterprise/aeboilerplate/tree/master/api/src/api) where I'm using express and how I handle calls.